# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

I am using gitlab ci for continues integration, I want to run unit test on my code and then build a docker image and then deploy it.
But the problem which I am facing is that how to run a docker service in gilab ci.

I get this error

```
"Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running"
```

after my docker build command is run.
do I need to install docker in gitlab-ci?

This is my .gitlab-ci.yml file

```
image: node:latest

before_script:

stages:
  - test
  - production
  - clean_up

services:
  - docker:dind

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm install -g swagger
    - npm test

production:
  type: deploy
  stage: production
  image: docker:latest
  script:
    - docker build -t testimage -t testimage:latest .
    - docker tag testimage docker.abc.xyz.com/testimage
    - docker push docker.abc.xyz.com/testimage
  only:
    - development

clean_up_job:
  stage: clean_up
  script:
    - rm -rf node_modules
    - npm uninstall -g swagger
  when: on_failure
```

I am not using GitLab Runner at the moment.

Comment: How are you running gitlab? Where is the docker engine you are supposed to build the image?

Comment: This could be related to the user permissions for the Docker Engine, check this https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user

Answer (score 2):

Try putting `services` inside `production` job, like this:

```
production:
  type: deploy
  stage: production
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - docker build -t testimage -t testimage:latest .
    - docker tag testimage docker.abc.xyz.com/testimage
    - docker push docker.abc.xyz.com/testimage
  only:
    - development
```

Comment: The key of the solution is the fact that we need the `docker:dind` service!

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
  --docker-privileged \
  --docker-volumes /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  --docker-volumes /home/gitlab-runner/docker-cache \
```

with set up of runners

you can check in `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` on server where your runners are set up